# Wrong time difference in minute/hour with joda API and UTC timezone

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jodatime, intervals

```
Date date = //getting Date object of (record inserted datetime) using Hibernate query . 
DateTime currentDateTime = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis(), DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println("Current Date Time " + currentDateTime);
DateTime utcDateTime = new DateTime(date, DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println("UTC Date Time :: " + utcDateTime);
Period per = new Period(currentDateTime.toLocalDateTime(), utcDateTime.toLocalDateTime());
System.out.println("Period time in sec ::" + (float) per.toStandardSeconds().getSeconds());
System.out.println("Period time in minutes::" + (float) per.toStandardSeconds().getSeconds() / 60);
System.out.println("Period time in hours::" + (float) per.toStandardSeconds().getSeconds() / (60 * 60));
```

I am using joda API and Hibernate while fetching data from MySQL DB. I am storing all data with UTC timezone in MySQL database. Now I want to get the time difference between current time and record inserted. My Local timezone is GMT+5:30. I am getting wrong hours (+5:30 hours with actual difference) in time difference. Don't know where I am doing mistake?
**EDIT :** 
I am using this code to store date in DB.

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format);
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
return dateTime.toString(dateTimeFormatter);
```

Comment: It's not at all clear that the problem is with Joda Time here. What is the value of `date`? (And is that a `java.sql.Date` or a `java.util.Date`?) What value has been recorded in the database? It doesn't help that you haven't shown us any of the values involved... and it's not clear why you're converting to `LocalDateTime` at all.

Comment: it's java.util.Date. See updated question.

Comment: I dont know how you went from the comment above to your edit...

Comment: I mentioned over there that I am getting Date object from DB.

Comment: Your question still doesn't show java.util.Date anywhere, and why are you using a *string* representation to store your date? And why have you still not provided any of the values? Basically there's so much that's unknown here, we can't help you...

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia: "Date object" could still be java.util.Date or java.sql.Date. Given that you're getting it from a *database*, java.sql.Date would actually be more common.

Comment: I really can't get how it is confusing. I am not using VARCHAR datetype in my DB, I am using DATETIME. I am just using String to store it. Will this make any problem? Other than just I am just storing and retrieving date from DB. And it is giving me wrong data. How? That is question. Please help me if possible

Comment: hie @JonSkeet, see my new question by which may be you will more clear : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823671/how-to-avoid-my-local-timezone-while-fetching-date-from-db-using-hibernate

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing and should be rewritten.

No need to call currentTimeMillis as DateTime does that by default.

No need to call toLocalDateTime. That would be used when you want to lose time zone, but you are already in UTC so no time zone applies so no need to drop time zone.

You are working too hard with the println lines calculating sec, minutes, hours. The [`PeriodFormatterBuilder`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/field/StrictDateTimeField.html) class performs such work.

You need to be clear about java.util.Date and java.sql.Date. The latter sets the time portion to zeros. Neither has a time zone. Be aware of a third type bundled with Java, [java.sql.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).

When debugging and posting this kind of question, get the milliseconds that back the Date and DateTime objects so we have accurate data. In my usual work I avoid using or thinking in milliseconds, but for debugging it can be useful.

As Jon Skeet said, you should store date-time values as date-time types in your database rather than strings.

I suggest you search StackOverflow for many similar questions providing example code.

Comment: Hi @Basil, really thanks for your answer and such nice suggestions. But I really can't get how it is confusing. I am not using `VARCHAR` datetype in my DB, I am using `DATETIME`. I am just using `String` to store it. Will this make any problem? Other than just I am just storing and retrieving date from DB. And it is giving me wrong data. How? That is question. Please help me if possible

Comment: see my new question by which may be you will more clear : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823671/how-to-avoid-my-local-timezone-while-fetching-date-from-db-using-hibernate